# How to delete a windows 10 directory?

Tags: windows-10

I am writing code in dotnet core 3.1, trying to create directory.

But accidentally created a directory with the name "Dev..".

Now, I can't delete this directory, and can't rename it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess explorer limitations keep you from deleting that folder.
If I were you, I'd try to delete directory same way it was created

```
if (Directory.Exists(root))  
{  
    Directory.Delete(root);  
}
```

Alternatively boot from live linux cd and delete that way.

Comment: Yes, I have just figured that out too. Not only explorer, command prompt also doesn't work. The worst is, I have "Dev" and "Dev.." side by side. When I delete "Dev..", it actually deleted my "Dev" folder. Luckily I have that in GitHub

Comment: Glad it worked out ;)